# From Dirac to Klein-Gordon in curved spacetime

Tags: spacetime, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

Is there an easy/elegant way of showing that "squaring" the Dirac equation in curved spacetime yields the Klein-Gordon equation, just like it happens in Minkowski space? A brute force approach would require a lot of tedious algebra dealing with the spin connection, the veilbein formalism and the Dirac matrices.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the squared Dirac equation (minimally) coupled to curvature does not give the Klein-Gordon equation (minimally) coupled to curvature. There appear additional terms. The same can be already observed in the coupling to the electromagnetic field.